# How to pass event from view page upper to ion-router-outlet

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

package.json

"@ionic/core": "^7.7.1"
"@ionic/vue": "^7.7.1"
"@ionic/vue-router": "^7.7.1"
"vue": "^3.4.16"
"vue-router": "^4.2.5"

App.vue

```js
<template>
   <ion-app>
        <component :is="layout" />
    </ion-app>
</template>
```

Layout.vue

```js
<template>
    <ion-page>
        <bar-header ref="barheader" />
    
        <ion-router-outlet
            @showBarHeader="showBarHeaderFunc" />
    </ion-page>
</template>

<script>
    ...
    methods: {
        showBarHeaderFunc(data) {
            this.$refs['barheader'].setBarStyle(data);
        },
    }
    ...
</script>
```

ViewPage.vue

```js
<script>
    ...
    async mounted() {
        this.$emit("showBarHeader", {customData: false});
    },
    ...
</script>
```

BarHeader.vue

```js
<template>
    <ion-header class="header-layout">
        <ion-toolbar color="app">
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
                <ion-back-button text="">
                    <i class="arrow-back" />
                </ion-back-button>
            </ion-buttons>
        </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
</template>
```

Emit **showBarHeader** (and other emits) not work with **ion-router-outlet**. If I use **router-view** it work, but then not work **ion-back-button**.